# Using Spring AOP, How can I intercept a exception just when it occurred?

Tags: spring, exception, aop, intercept

Some code like this:

```
public class A {

    @Autoware
    private B b;  

    public void a() {
        //AAA: some logic process that maybe throw exception
        b.b();
    }

}

public class B {

    public void b() {
        //BBB: some logic process maybe also throw exception
    }

}
```

Both exceptions in A.a() and B.b() need to be intercept, so i use @AfterThrowing annotation do it. but the question is, when i call A.a() in other code and exception has occurred in B.b(), the Advice will execute twice! because exception that occurred in B.b() was propagating to its caller A.a().

**I can't swallow the exception** silently, because i use spring-amqp, above codes is on Consumer side, i need some message processing that based on the exceptions that occurred in Consumer.

@Around does not work too since i can't swallow the throwed exception.

So, How can i intercept a exception just when it occurred? ignore propagation of it.

Any reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does your code care how often the exception is seen?

Comment: Because in Advice I need insert one record into database once a exception was throwed. If Advice execute twice, two db records will be inserted that is not what i expected.